# What to send input text data to div

Tags: angularjs, binding

**html Code**

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
<div style="text-align: center">
<div>
   {{great}}
</div>
<form>
   <div class="list">
      <div class="list list-inset">
         <label class="item item-input">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" height="20" placeholder="Add Note" ng-model="searchText">
         </label>
         <button class="button button-block"  ng-click="addTag()">Add Note</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.searchText ="  ";
$scope.great = "Note Here";
$scope.addTag = function () {
    $scope.great == $scope.searchText;   
};
```

I am trying to add a note to my tasks that I create.  Here is my app:

https://behrouz2000.fwd.wf

When you click on the task and click a note it should create that note one on top of each other with a minute time stamp.

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: As you can see in the link when I click add note nothing happens.

Comment: use `$scope.great = $scope.searchText;` instead of `$scope.great == $scope.searchText;`

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning you should use one equal

```
 $scope.great = $scope.searchText;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {

   $scope.searchText ="Note Here";
    $scope.great = [];
    $scope.addTag = function () {
        $scope.great = $scope.searchText;
    };
 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
    <div style="text-align: center">
       <div>
            {{great}}
       </div>
       <div class="list">
         <div class="list list-inset">
         <label class="item item-input">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" height="20" placeholder="Add Note" ng-model="searchText">
         </label>
         <button class="button button-block"  ng-click="addTag()">Add Note</button>
         </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the link, I added your code and still no result.

Comment: i checked your code, the click event does not get fired in your link

Comment: it just prints out a blank string.

Comment: when I add ng-controller="ToDoListCtrl" to the div we tried it freezes